# How to transfer data from a listbox to a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox, picturebox

I have a form which contains a listbox which is connected to a dataset, listview and 2 picture boxes.

The data which fills the listbox is the title of a photo

When an item(title) is selected in the listbox the image that its related too shows up in picturebox1. This is fine ive got this all to work.

However I then should be able to move the selected item into the listview and the when i select an item in listview the image should show up in the picturebox2. This is where the problem occurs.

I cant find a way in which to store the picture with that title when transferred over.

I dont mind if the listview is changed to a listbox. it makes no difference to me.

Comment: so what you are saying is that you want the picturebox2 to bind on listview which is binded on listbox which is binded on the dataset?

Comment: listview isnt bound onto the listbox i can just move items over to it.

Comment: Are you asking how to do drag&drop?

Comment: ok, well the only thing that pops in my mind (as your first binding functions well) is that the item you move to your listview isn't the proper object, so that the picturebox can't be filled.

Comment: its moving over but the listview isnt bound to anythin so all thats moving over is the title